# Function Point Analysis in SAS

Tags: project-management, sas, function-points

Would some be able to help me with some links on how FPA is done for SAS related projects.If someone of yuo have already done I guess it would be even more usefull if yuo could share some tips on how it could be done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an introductory article on Function Point Analysis:
[Function Point Estimation](http://geekswithblogs.net/Prabhats/archive/2007/03/01/107632.aspx)

I use following online Function Point Calculator tool from developergeeks.com. It's very friendly to use:
[Online Function Point Calculator](http://developergeeks.com/functionpoint.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I think the question is a bit too broad. FPA is a big subject area and has some general guidelines around how it is conducted. ( See a good article here: [clicky](http://www.qpmg.com/fp-intro.htm) ) I don't know of any specific examples where SAS was incorporated. However this type of analysis lends itself more to the processes and software functions and therefore is fairly language agnostic.

Maybe we could discuss this in more detail if we talked about a specific SAS program, macro or operation.